# Surjective group homomorphism sending minimal generating system to minimal generating system

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is the following statement true: Any surjective homomorphism $f:G\to H$ of groups with equal rank maps every minimal generating system $x$ of $G$ to a minimal generating system $y$ of $H$? "Minimal generating set" means "generating set of minimal cardinality". Is it only valid for finite rank? How about infinite rank?

Comment: (1) Could you replace "a" with either "some" or "every" to clarify the question? (2) (after Igor's comment): minimal means, not properly containing any generating subset. There are often minimal generating subsets that don't achieve the rank (e.g., $S_n$ generated by $n-1$ transpositions while it's also 2-generated). If you mean "of minimal cardinal", please correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that "minimal generating set" means "a generating set that does not properly contain a generating set" (that is, every proper subset does not generate). In that reading, the statement is false in both finite and infinite ranks.

For a counterexample in finite rank, let $G$ be infinite cyclic generated by $x$ (rank $1$), and $H$ be cyclic of order $2$ generated by $y$ (also rank $1$). Let $f\colon G\to H$ be the map sending $x$ to $y$. The minimal generating set $\{x^2,x^3\}$ (which generates $G$, but no proper subset does) is mapped to $\{e,y\}$, which is not minimal. Or you could take $H$ to be cyclic of order $4$, if you want to avoid the trivial element, as then you get $y^2$ and $y^3$; which is not minimal.

For infinite rank, take $G=H$ be a direct sum of countably infinitely many copies of the infinite cyclic group; take $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ as a basis for $G$, and $\{y_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ as a basis for $H$. Take $f\colon G\to H$ be the map that sends $x_{2i-1}$ to $y_i$ and $x_{2i}$ to $y_i^{-1}$.

---

If by "minimal generating set" you mean "generating set of minimal cardinality", then given that the rank of a group is the least cardinality of a generating set, then the answer is positive: under a surjective homomorphism, a generating set is mapped to a generating set. So if $X$ is a generating set for $G$ with $\mathrm{rank}(G)$ elements, then $f(X)$ is a generating set for $H$ with at most $\mathrm{rank}(G)=\mathrm{rank}(H)$ elements, and since any generating set has at least $\mathrm{rank}(H)$ elements, it follows that $f(X)$ has exactly $\mathrm{rank}(H)$ elements (in cardinality) and so is a generating set of minimal cardinality.

Comment: It is not clear that this is what the OP means by "minimal". He could mean "of mininal cardinality".

Comment: @IgorRivin: If that's the case, then the answer is trivially yes, since generating sets map to generating sets under surjective maps.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you also interpreted "a" as "every". I'm still waiting for clarification from the OP.

Comment: I am not arguing that point.

Comment: @YCor: The second part would show that "there exists a minimal generating set (whether of minimal cardinality or minimal in not properly containing a generating set) that is mapped to a minimal generating set" holds.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm aware that when there are 4 interpretations of a question due to two boolean discussions, one option is to solve all four questions, pick the one which seems the less trivial, and answer it. Still, I've seem several instances on this site where the non-trivial interpretation was not the correct one. In any case, I'm asking for clarification and will vote to close as unclear if it doesn't come.